# Why does Php Curl keep trying to use Tor

Tags: php, curl, tor

Neither this or any of my other curl scripts work properly. None of them are currently set to use Tor, although I did try to implement it recently. The CLI curl program also tries to connect with Tor. I purged the package from my system, reinstalled, and it's still the same. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$cha = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($cha, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
CURL_SETOPT($cha, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm');
$content = curl_exec($cha);
if (preg_match('/(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/',$content)) echo "yep"; else echo "nope";
echo $content;
curl_close();
?>
```

Comment: What OS are you using? What package are you talking about? And what does your request look like?

Comment: root@henry-NC10:/home/henry/php# php proxygrab.php
* About to connect() to proxy 127.0.0.1 port 9050 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... * connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9050 (#0)
> GET http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: www.samair.ru
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 501 Tor is not an HTTP Proxy

Comment: Great :) Now it will be easier to help you! Put the information in your question so it's easier to read out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try looking at your environment - use the “printenv” or “env” commands. There may be a stray *proxy setting there.

Comment: I should also note that your script works for me here locally without using tor.